# How to warp asp.net core api action result data by code&message&data without edit/add code in action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to `not edit/add action code` and wrap action result data by `code&message&data`,for example,below is my expected result :

```
{"code":20000,"message":"","data":[{"id":1,"val":"hello s.o"}]}
```

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

api.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class ShDjController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> UnCheckList()
    {
        return new []{new{id=1,val="hello s.o"}};
    }
}
```

### what i've tried :

I'm tring to use `ActionFilter` to do it,but still not work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `ActionFilter` to deal this problem like below code (but it's rough & need optimization)

startup.cs config :

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(config =>{
                config.Filters.Add(new ServerApp.Filters.ActionFilter());
            }).AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }
```

action filter.cs :

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
    public class ActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context){ }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if(context.Result?.GetType()==typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)){
                var result = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)context.Result;
                var newVal = new {
                    status = 20000,
                    message = "",
                    data = result.Value
                };
                result.Value = newVal;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

refer :

- https://blog.johnwu.cc/article/ironman-day14-asp-net-core-filters.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example class:

```
public class A
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<B> Data { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

Return in your api type: IEnumerable UnCheckList()

```
return new A
{
    Code = 2000,
    Message = "message",
    Data = new List<B> { new B { Id = 1, Val ="val"} }
}
```

maybe you saying about Middleware.
You should add in your startup.cs code line app.UseMiddleware();
and then implement class in Invoke method.

```
public class CusomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CusomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {

        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,but it need to edit action method code,if there's 100 method you need to copy/paste 100 times.

Comment: pls, UseMiddleware for all your responses.You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: ,yes,i upvote the edit,middleware it's the way i'm tring now

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DataReponse<T> where T : class 
{
    public int Code {get; set;}
    public int Message {get; set;}
    public List<T> Data {get; set;}
}
```

In services, you would like using

```
return new DataReponse<your model> 
{
  ....
}
```

In Controller, you just return Ok(your response of service).

Otherwise, you should using middleware for exception at applicaiton. You dont care about return 200, 404,....

Comment: thanks,i upvote this,i used to code like this before but it also need edit/add action method code.

Comment: and right now i'm thinking how to deal the status problem.

Answer (score 1):

For example middleware exception in dealing with status code problem:
In startup:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ApiExceptionHandlerMiddleware>()
```

Create new class

```
public class ApiExceptionHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// ApiExceptionHandlerMiddleware
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="next"></param>
        /// <param name="logger"></param>
        public ApiExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ApiExceptionHandlerMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (DomainException domainException)
            {
                var err = new DomainExceptionContract()
                {
                    Key = domainException.Key,
                    Message = domainException.Message
                };

                _logger.LogError(domainException, domainException.Message);

                await WriteErrorMessageToResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, err);
            }
            catch (ForbiddenException forbiddenException)
            {
                var err = new DomainExceptionContract()
                {
                    Key = "Forbidden",
                    Message = forbiddenException.Message
                };

                _logger.LogError(forbiddenException, err.Message);

                await WriteErrorMessageToResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, err);
            }
            catch (AuthorizationException authorizationException)
            {
                var err = new DomainExceptionContract()
                {
                    Key = "Unauthorized",
                    Message = authorizationException.Message
                };

                _logger.LogError(authorizationException, err.Message);

                await WriteErrorMessageToResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, err);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var err = new DomainExceptionContract()
                {
                    Key = "InternalServerError",
                    Message = ex.Message
                };

                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message, new object[] { });

                await WriteErrorMessageToResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, err);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// WriteErrorMessageToResponse
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="httpStatusCode"></param>
        /// <param name="error"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task WriteErrorMessageToResponse(HttpContext context, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, DomainExceptionContract error)
        {
            context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
            context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";

            var response = new { Data = error };
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(), Formatting = Formatting.Indented });

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
```