# 400 badrequest when passing int instead string in web api .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need custom message for my request.

Currently I am passing below request json from postman

```json
{
    "countryid": "14sdsads02"
}
```

but my model is

```
public class model
{
    public int countryid {get;set;}
}
```

When pass request from postman, I am getting below error

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|21793cf-495c68ddbc92ab35.",
    "errors": {
        "$.countryid": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.countryid | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 29."
        ]
    }
}
```

**But instead of this, I need custom error in my web api. How can I achieve this?**

Comment: @PeterCsala . Please under stand i know what is type difference. Only vulnerability purpose i need to stop my property exposing. So how my server level response to customize.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I left a solution proposal with the desired behaviour.

Comment: What is the format that you want to custom error?For how to custom error message you could refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/62989600/11398810.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define a custom response in case of 400 then you can do the followings:

#### The handler

In order to catch the model binding errors you have to wire up a handler for the `ApiBehaviorOptions`'s `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.invalidmodelstateresponsefactory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)).

The required delegate is quite generic: `Func<ActionContext, IActionResult>`.  So, first let's create an interface for this:

```cs
public interface IModelBindingErrorHandler
{
    IActionResult HandleInvalidModelState(ActionContext context);
}
```

Here is a simple handler implementation:

```cs
public class ModelBindingErrorHandler : IModelBindingErrorHandler
{
    private ICorrelationContextAccessor correlationContextAccessor;
    private ILogger logger;

    public ModelBindingErrorHandler(ICorrelationContextAccessor correlationContextAccessor, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.correlationContextAccessor = correlationContextAccessor;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult HandleInvalidModelState(ActionContext context)
    {
        string correlationId = correlationContextAccessor.CorrelationContext?.CorrelationId;

        var modelErrors = context.ModelState
            .Where(stateEntry => stateEntry.Value.Errors.Any())
            .Select(stateEntry => new InvalidData
            {
                FieldName = stateEntry.Key,
                Errors = stateEntry.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
            });

        logger.LogError("The request contained malformed input.", modelErrors);

        var responseBody = new GlobalErrorModel
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the request contains invalid data. Please revise.", 
            ErrorTracingId = correlationId
        };
    
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(responseBody);
    }
}
```

The helper classes

```cs
public class GlobalErrorModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string ErrorTracingId { get; set; }
}

public class InvalidData
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string[] Errors { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{FieldName}: {string.Join("; ", Errors)}";
}
```

#### Self-registration

```cs
public static class ModelBindingErrorHandlerRegister
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method should be called after <b>AddControllers();</b> call.
    /// </summary>
    public static IServiceCollection AddModelBinderErrorHandler(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return AddModelBinderErrorHandler<ModelBindingErrorHandler>(services);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be used to register a custom Model binder's error handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TImpl">A custom implementation of <see cref="IModelBindingErrorHandler"/></typeparam>
    public static IServiceCollection AddModelBinderErrorHandler<TImpl>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where TImpl : class, IModelBindingErrorHandler
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IModelBindingErrorHandler, TImpl>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var handler = serviceProvider.GetService<IModelBindingErrorHandler>();
        services.PostConfigure((ApiBehaviorOptions options) =>
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = handler.HandleInvalidModelState);

        return services;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        
        //Omited for brevity
        
        services.AddModelBinderErrorHandler();
    }
    
    //Omited for brevity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is worked for me. Bit I didn't understand what is correlationContextAccessor and what is package for this in .net core 3.1

Comment: @valuesoft It is an external nuget package, called [CorrelationId](https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId). It helps you to create ids in distributed tracing.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to change type of `countryid` from `int` to `string` in your model"

```
public class model
{
  public string countryid {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your controller check if the value is convertible to `int` or not. If not, return a customized `BadRequest` response:

```
int countryid;
if (!int.TryParse(model.countryid, out countryid))
  return BadRequest("Your customized error message");
```